# Multiple url with 2 different twig and 1 controller

Tags: symfony, routes, twig

I have to write a web application that is accesible to 2 different url :

url_1: http://pippo.weapp.it
url_2: http://pluto.weapp.it

the logic of the application is the same but change the template .
There is a way to write 1 controller that render go to 2 different folder twig or what is the best solution ??
I see many solution only with multiple controller

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To render different view with one controller, you can check the route name in your controller and render the view you want

Answer (score 0):

No sure if I'm getting well what you want, but you can do, in the controller. If the host is different, you can also modify de "host" value:

```
/**
 * @Route("/route1", name="route1", host="pippo.weapp.it")
 * @Route("/route2", name="route2", host="pluto.weapp.it")
 * @Method("GET")
 */

if (condition) {  
    $response = $this->render('template1.html.twig');
} else {
    $response = $this->render('template2.html.twig');
}

return $response;
```

Comment: this is a good alternative ..but i remember (maybe bad remember ) that you can set two different path in twig config   twig:
    twig: # ...
    paths:
       url1: theme1folder
        'url2': theme2folder                                                                                                         and controller go to the folder theme ... maybe i have bad memory

Answer (score 0):

this is a good alternative ..but i remember (maybe bad remember ) that you can set two different path in twig config

```
twig: # ...
paths:
   url1: theme1folder
    'url2': theme2folder
```

and controller go to the folder theme ... maybe i have bad memory